# How to mount two Dynamic PVC in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a scenario to mount two Dynamic PVC in Minikube, when i tried the below manifest file, I can see only one volume mounted in the POD, when i describe pod, i can see both volumes bounded, not sure what is the cause.

````
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: niranjan-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: praveen-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: praveen-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: niranjan-pv
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: niranjan-pvc
    - name: praveen-pv
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: praveen-pvc
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/tmp/niranjan-mount"
          name: niranjan-pv
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/tmp/praveen-mount"
          name: praveen-pv ```

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyNKg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nDPl.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOrq2.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `volumeMounts`, you should provide only one value with an array:

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: praveen-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: niranjan-pv
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: niranjan-pvc
    - name: praveen-pv
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: praveen-pvc
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/tmp/niranjan-mount"
          name: niranjan-pv
        - mountPath: "/tmp/praveen-mount"
          name: praveen-pv
```

If not one of those variables will override the value of the second one, and you will have only one mounted volume.

Comment: Thank you Hussein Awala for your reply,  Is there any way to overcome the override.

Comment: I provided the correct manifest in my answer, just update your pod using it

Comment: Hi Hussein Awala,

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but seems i missed something, didnt work.
```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/tmp/niranjan-mount"
          name: niranjan-pv
        - mountPath: "/tmp/praveen-mount"
          name: praveen-pv
```

Comment: What do you get when you describe the pod: `kubectl describe pod praveen-pod`

Comment: ` Volumes:
  niranjan-pv:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  niranjan-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  praveen-pv:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  praveen-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
`

Comment: Kubectl describe shows both volumes are claimed, but not mounted in the pod